# Sequential Criterion for Limits Confusion

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Define $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ by $f(x) = 5x$ if $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $f(x) = x^2 + 6$ if $x \in n\mathbb{Q}$. Using the Sequential Criterion to show that $f$ is discontinuous at 1 and continuous at 2.

---

I'm not really sure how to start this off. The fact that $f$ is piecewise and in two different sets is throwing me off.

Comment: What is $n\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: I don't know. It's just what is written in the exercise

Comment: Ok, start by figuring out what they mean by that!

Comment: It is a really weird notation, but clearly means $\mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q$.

Comment: @Arkamis Well, via Martin, it apparently means $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$!

Comment: @MartinArgerami Well, do you any ideas?

Comment: At $1$, you have to find two sequences $\{x_n\}$ and $\{y_n\}$, both converging to $1$, such that $f(x_n)\to5$ and $f(y_n)\to7$. At $2$ you have to show that for any sequence $\{z_n\}$ that converges to $2$, $f(z_n)\to10$.